# How to get position of old spritenode to use for new spritenode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In my brickgame I want bricks placed on top of each other.

I created a `BrickNode` Class. Here are different sized bricks created to be called in the main file.

```
#import "BrickNode.h"

@implementation BrickNode

- (instancetype) init {
    if (self == [super init]) {

        int number = arc4random() % 2;

        if (number == 0) {
            SKSpriteNode *bridge1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"TestBridgePiece"];
            bridge1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
            [self addChild:bridge1];
        }
        if (number == 1) {
            SKSpriteNode *bridge2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"TestBridgePiece1"];
            bridge2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
            [self addChild:bridge2];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I created the method for calling the class. This method is going to be called in `TouchesBegin`. Because I want the user to be able to spawn the next brick.

```
 -(void)spawnBrick
    {
        BrickNode *newBrick = [[BrickNode alloc] init];
        newBrick.position = CGPointMake(0.0, <#CGFloat y#>)
    }
```

However the problem is the position of the new brick. I need the positioning information of the brick that has just been loaded to know where to locate the new brick.

Comment: look into enumerateChildNodesWithName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
[self.parent.children objectAtIndex:([self.parent.children count] - 2)] ;
```

After you add the new brick to its parent node to get any node that was previously added before it.  If you are adding Brick and a non Brick, this won't work, but if have it structured that a SKNode only holds Brick, then this will get you the previous brick that was added.

Note,  I did not check this to see if the objective C was correct,  but the concept of it is correct.

The algorithm:

Call parent node,
Call children of parent node,
Go to the very end of the children nodes (this is currently the newest brick added),
Get the index before the very end,
Return the SKNode at this index.

Comment: Thanks for helping:) I understand the concept. I did a lot of figuring only don't know which code where to place to get it working. Since I am new to coding an example would be very helpful to me.

Comment: I would need more details on your code,  I would be adding this when you need to position your next brick.  basically `oldBrick = code above`,  `newBrick position = oldBrick position + height`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I tried. Only problem it is incompatible to assign a 'Bricknode oldBrick' to an 'SKNode'. I tried to make 'oldBrick' an 'SKNode', but then I couldn't found no previous bricks loaded. What is best to do?

Comment: Yeah i really cant help you with this part. You would need to  go find tutorials on how subclassing works